# Processing large amount of WhatsApp jpeg files in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg, whatsapp

When I tried to open a jpeg file, downloaded from WhatsApp in Adobe Photoshop I've got the following Photoshop error:

> Could not complete your request because a SOFn, DQT, or DHT JPEG marker is missing before a JPEG SOS marker

[image: ErrorDialogBox]

Google search advised to open broken file in MS Paint and then save it again. But for large amount of broken files it is not a convenient way I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to create a free open source tool to solve this task and help others, who experience the same issue.

The project page with the source code: https://github.com/cdefgah/whatsapp-jpeg-repair

Application releases page (for Windows and MacOS): https://github.com/cdefgah/whatsapp-jpeg-repair/releases

Expand 'Assets' section (marked by green rectangle on the picture below) and download the application zip-file relevant to your operating system.

[image: Application release]

Answer (score -1):

I can fix it with opening the JPG file in the Microsoft Paint and Save it.
 That's all! Then the Photoshop can open it.

Comment: What if you have 250 broken files?

Comment: This is a quick fix (workaround) for those that want to open small amount of files without dealing with third-party software.

Comment: No offense, but did you read the original post? :) This approach is described in the original question at the top of the page :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right

Answer (score -2):

Drag all the files together to Acrobat pdf and combine into one PDF file - then export to JPEG.